# Set Input Type = "File" HTML5 parent directory

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, input-type-file

I want to upload a file onto a server so I am using HTML5 input type file element. For example

`<input type="file" name="file" id="idfile" accept=".sys*" />`

Now for the user, he/she selects a file from "D:\User\TestLand\abc.Sys" location

So what I want is when again a user wants to upload another file then the file selection popup comes with "D:\User\TestLand" directory instead of download directory.

This feature is already present in Chrome, but not in IE9 or above and I want to add this feature also for IE.

Comment: add more description about your question.

Comment: @KevinAndrid, I hope this time it is much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can control from the browser unfortunately. For security the directory path is hidden from the HTML/JS code and you can't set the path with with the HTML5 File API.

Chrome's behaviour is to show the same directory that the user previously used but it looks as though IE chooses not to do this. Filing it as a bug/feature request with Microsoft is probably the only option (unless it's been already implemented the latest version).